# Can I change a web page's scale?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, webkit

**I really would love to scale webpages down or up. Is there any way I can implement this?**

Comment: Scale? Don't you mean zoom in/out like as you achieve with `Ctrl`+Scrollwheel?

Comment: Scale up in your browser, or scale it up in *everyones* browser?

Comment: @Matt: within everyones browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this CSS on your container element:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-moz-transform: scale(2);
transform: scale(2);
```

A post with more information on CSS3 transforms:
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/

Comment: @Mark: GREAT STUFF! THANK YOU SO MUCH! =D Do you have a good link to point me to, where it goes a little more in depth? =)

Comment: Interesting. How cross-browser is the `transform` property?

Comment: @RadiantHex this link is pretty good: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/

Comment: @Piskvor It's a CSS3 property. It's supported on all major browsers except IE.

Comment: @Mark: this answer has made my day! =D Thanks! If you could put the link inside the answer, for other people to see that would be awesome. Ticking as soon as SO lets me!

Comment: I've been using this, but it looks as though I'm going to have to pull the feature, as I'm experiencing an array of rendering problems, from lightboxes not being drawn correctly, to content not scrolling correctly. Anything which requires a page redraw can conflict with css scale, so if you do use it, please do test across all browsers for unexpected behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

In IE you can use the css property `zoom`.